# Incorrect color in pixel from original image with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, image, colors, uiimage

I'm converting an image from original image to 128 x 128 pixels. I tried to retrieve all colors from the original image for each pixel, but why are some colors off? For example, the original photo shows orange / red on top of the mountain (sunrise), but why do I see blue instead of orange / red after pulling all colors from the image? What went wrong with me?

I tried use PNG image from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203903/swift-reading-jpg-image-for-pixel-color-returning-incorrect-values), same result.

My code is as follows:

```
func findColors(image: UIImage) -> [UIColor] {
    var preRawColor = [UIColor]()
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage,
        let data = cgImage.dataProvider?.data,
        let bytes = CFDataGetBytePtr(data) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't access image data")
    }
    assert(cgImage.colorSpace?.model == .rgb)

    let bytesPerPixel = cgImage.bitsPerPixel / cgImage.bitsPerComponent
    for y in 0 ..< cgImage.height {
        for x in 0 ..< cgImage.width {
            let offset = (y * cgImage.bytesPerRow) + (x * bytesPerPixel)
            let components = (r: bytes[offset], g: bytes[offset + 1], b: bytes[offset + 2])
            //print("[x:\(x), y:\(y)] \(components)")
            preRawColor.append(UIColor(red: CGFloat(components.r)/255, green: CGFloat(components.g)/255, blue: CGFloat(components.b)/255, alpha: 1))
        }
    }
    return preRawColor
}
```

To show the picture using uiview:

```
for rowX in 0..<256 {
    for colX in 0..<256 {
        let boxTapped = TheLabelTap(target: self, action: #selector(self.boxTapped))
        let boxBtn = pixelBox()
        boxTapped.getView = boxBtn
        
        let getDetail = findColors(image: resizeImage)
        boxTapped.name = "\(getDetail.number)"
        
        boxBtn.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(colX) * boxSizeSet, y: CGFloat(rowX) * boxSizeSet, width: boxSizeSet, height: boxSizeSet)
        boxBtn.colX = colX
        boxBtn.rowX = rowX
        if getDetail.isCompleted == true {
            boxBtn.backgroundColor = getDetail.originalColor
            boxBtn.textColor = .label.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        } else {
            boxBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Pixel Box Background")
            boxBtn.textColor = .label.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        }
        boxBtn.text = "\(getDetail.number)"
        boxBtn.textAlignment = .center
        boxBtn.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        boxBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        boxBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.imageBoxMain.addSubview(boxBtn)
        boxBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        boxBtn.addGestureRecognizer(boxTapped)

        numberOfBoxCreated += 1
    }
}
```

Original picture:

[image]

Result picture: (I'm not sure why the color on top of the mountain appears to be blue.)

[image]

Comment: your problem probably is not getting the pixel colours, but calculating the average color to use in your reduced image - how do you calculate the average pixel color?

Comment: I already resize image into 128 x 128 before getting the color from pixel

Comment: so how does the 128x128 image look like? in your post I only see the highres original and a wrong-coloured downsized one ...

Comment: The original image has perfect color, but when I converted it to an array, it was successful. However, when I pull color from array (uicolor), I notice that some colors are incorrect. Do you see purple on the mountaintop? Pink was supposed to be the color. I tried a new picture of myself; my skin is tanned, but when I converted it to uicolor, it turned out that my skin is purple.

Comment: yes, that's why I want to see how you calculate the reduced image - apparently the color calculation for the image conversion is incorrect. You can see that _all_ your colours are off from the original colours, it's just more apparent ofr the orange parts

Comment: it almost looks like your conversion mixes up the red/green/blue parts of the pixel (eg set the red part in the blue part etc) - for grey areas that results in a different greyish tint, for red that would turn into blue

Comment: how can I fix it? I couldn't solve it in many method

Comment: show me the conversion code, without it I can't tell you

Comment: Ok I added some code here, if this isn't enough information, let me know